# Grails war command defaults to development environment under netbeans

Tags: grails, netbeans

When I generate the war in my grails app via right-click / run grails / command / war, it shows "Environment set to development", having it run without parameters. Why is this happening when according to the docs it should default to production (which is what I need)?

BTW, is there a way having built the whole grails application with NetBeans to use the command line to generate the wars ?

Versions: NetBeans 6.7.1, Grails 1.2
OS: Ubuntu 9.1

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The netbeans plugin is probably running the command "grails dev war" which creates a war file based on the development settings. The normal "grails war" command uses production settings.
You should just be able to change to the directory containing your grails-app and src folders and run the command

```
grails war
```

This assumes that you have grails installed and on your path.

Comment: It worked just fine. I assume it's a plugin glitch, I'll go with the direct command from now on. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

No, only that grails war may assume it to be a development. I suggest you specifically type as follow:

```
grails prod war
```

Answer (score 0):

you can modify the proyect file gradle.properties and add

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Dgrails.env=dev    //for development
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Dgrails.env=prod   //for production enviroment
```

Check https://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/gettingStarted.html